# cookie value is undefined (react-cookie 2.0.6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-redux

I have a problem with implementing react cookies v^2. I use webpack-dev-server for testing.
Here is a conlose log:

Warning: Failed context type: The context `cookies` is marked as required in `withCookies(App)`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in withCookies(App)
          in Provider

/App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CookiesProvider, withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie'
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

//import RequireAuth from './RequireAuth';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';
import LandingPage from './LandindPage';
import WorkSpace from './WorkSpace';
import ActivationPage from './ActivationPage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route path="/workspace" component={WorkSpace}/>
            <Route exact path="/activation" component={ActivationPage}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </CookiesProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```

/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './components/App';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: So, to solve the problem I've changed the react-cookie lib to universal-cookie and it works. But the question remains, why it's not defined? Should it be defined on the server side? (but there is an example in the README on react-cookie github without server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the functionality previously present in the `react-cookie` npm package has been moved to `universal-cookie`. The relevant example from the [universal-cookie repository](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie) now is:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('myCat', 'Pacman', { path: '/' });
console.log(cookies.get('myCat')); // Pacman
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684059/4279419) (all credits to author of the orginal answer)

Answer (score 5):

## HttpOnly

If you're convinced you're using `universal-cookie` (or similar package) correctly, and still getting `undefined`:
**Check (in the source code) how the cookie is being set** (or inspect it with a cookie inspector browser extension, like [EditThisCookie for Chrome](http://www.editthiscookie.com/), and check the `HttpOnly`property).
If `HttpOnly` is set to `true`, then (by definition) no javascript will be able to access it (that's [the point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691716/870121) of `HttpOnly`). Hence the value would be returned as `undefined`.

From [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies):

> #### Restrict access to cookies
>
> A cookie with the `HttpOnly` attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript `Document.cookie` API; it is sent only to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting ([XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#Cross-site_scripting_(XSS))) attacks.