# How to set up cookie in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have finished code a welcome box and that can be closed by clicking the button. This welcome is just a part of the page, now, I want to add cookie in this component, in order to achieve this welcome box will show up for only once for each browser. 
I am newbie for cookie, any suggestion will help me.

```js
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div className="container">
         <p>Welcome to our website</p>
         <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>close me</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
});

var ShowHide = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { childVisible: true };
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        {
          this.state.childVisible
            ? <Child onClick={this.onClick} />
            : null
        }
      </div>
    )
  },
  
  onClick: function() {
    this.setState({childVisible: !this.state.childVisible});
  }
});
 
React.render(<ShowHide />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit following link. You need to import react-cookie

[How can I do to set cookie in the react code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826992/how-can-i-do-to-set-cookie-in-the-react-code)