# Set up cookie for the component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have read this article [How can I do to set cookie in the react code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826992/how-can-i-do-to-set-cookie-in-the-react-code) about setting up cookie in reactjs code, however, I cannot use any library, what I can use is just the javascrip. 
Now, what I want to achieve is to show up a welcome box for the first time visit.
What I have done and tested are: 1.the welcome box, it is a component coding in jsx; 2. the cookie coding in js. Both sub-part are tested working, however, when I tried to combine these two part into a single component, it is not working.

```js
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div className="container">
         <p>Welcome to our website</p>
         <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me to close</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
});

var ShowHide = React.createClass({
createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }
 else var expires = "";
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
},

readCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
 return "";
},

eraseCookie(name) {
 createCookie(name,"",-1);
},

firstVisit() {
  var isFirstVisit;
 var result = readCookie('firstVisit');
    if (result == "") {
        createCookie('firstVisit', 'true', 365);
        isFirstVisit = true;
  return isFirstVisit;
    }
    else {
  isFirstVisit = false;
  return isFirstVisit;
 }
},
  
getInitialState: function () {
    if(firstVisit()) {
      return { childVisible: true };
    }
    else 
    {
      return { childVisible: true };
    }
},

onClick: function() {
  this.setState({childVisible: !this.state.childVisible});
},
  
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        {
          this.state.childVisible
            ? <Child onClick={this.onClick} />
            : null
        }
      </div>
    )
  },
});
 
React.render(<ShowHide />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for you to use cookies? Might be easier to use `localStorage` instead.

Comment: If doing that, could you give me some instruction or related article, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to cookies you could use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Here's a basic example of that. It sets an item in the storage once the main component is mounted and reacts to that item in the `render()` method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Get item from localStorage and save it to a constant.
  const hasVisitedBefore = localStorage.getItem('hasVisitedBefore');

  // Check if the user has visited the site (component) before.
  if (!hasVisitedBefore) {
    // If not, set the component state (or dispatch an action if you need)
    // Also set the localStorage so it's globally accessible.
    this.setState({ hasVisitedBefore: false });
    localStorage.setItem('hasVisitedBefore', true);
  }
}

// Based on the state set in `componentDidMount()`, show or hide the welcome modal.
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.hasVisitedBefore
        ? 'Welcome back!'
        : 'Welcome for the first time!'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Working demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/31hxwmg0/).

In other components you could then just check for `localStorage.getItem('hasVisitedBefore')` and render things based on that.

Comment: I am really appreciate for your help, now, I have achieved what I need to do.