# How to get JWT cookies in our react application, how to check the user is login or not I am unable to find how to handle my react application session

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, redux

How to get JWT cookies in our react application, how to check the user is login or not I am unable to find how to handle my react application session.

I really appreciate who helps me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826992/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-in-react

Comment: I didn't get cookies in response. JWT cookies store in the browser and also I am not able to see cookies.

Comment: when I call login API with login credentials, getting results ok on the body but I didn't get cookies or token in the body. so how to get cookies on the client-side for the application authentication.

Comment: It's long to explain but I suggest you this [**repository**](https://github.com/haichao-yu/react-redux-blog) because everything is there(check user connected...)

Comment: J.Antonio Thanks but in my case this is my server-side code `res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3600000 });
  res.status(200).send({ auth: true });` in response only true no token

Answer (score 6):

The server side API is setting the `HTTPOnly` cookie which you wont be able to read in JS.
What you need to do it in your react App handle a `401` status error and based on that set a flag `isAuthenticated` or something  as false. Otherwise keep it to be true. With each request to the server `HTTPOnly` cookie would be sent automatically so you don't need to handle the token inside a cookie.
The backend code needs to send a `401` once the cookie is expired, or the logout is requested or the JWT inside a cookie expires.

Comment: Yes if your app is using httpOnly cookie this is the right way. You should not be storing your tokens in localStorage.

Comment: but I have a question about why I am not able to see cookies on our browser I think in server hand need enable something.

Comment: No Sir it might be using HttpOnly cookies. They are secure cookies and can't and should not be accessed using client side javascript.

Comment: Please refer to that.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Answer (score 5):

Before I say anything, you have included `app.use(cookieParser())` in `index.js` right? Because if not, you're gonna need that once you've installed it with [`npm i cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser)

But anyway, a few things:

1. You can create a [PrivateRoute](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) in React, as far as I'm aware this tends to work well to protect routes from unauthorized users.
2. You can simply store an `isAuthenticated` in either the `state` or `localStorage`: however this will require that you make **absolutely** sure that a user shouldn't be able to just change the value in the `state` or add `isAuthenticated` in `localStorage` and just spoof authenticity (this is the part that took me the longest to get right).

---

Anyway, the way I've handled this is that when a user logs in an `access token` (and a `refresh token` if it doesn't already exists) are generated from the server and sent to the client in an `httpOnly` cookie, while this makes it so that you can't do anything with it on the client side with JavaScript as [Pavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4557914/pavan) pointed out in his answer (which is generally a good thing), you should use `res.status` for validation when you make the `fetch` request. Here's what my `fetch` request kind of looks like:

```
const login = async (user) => {
        const body = JSON.stringify(user);
        return fetch(loginURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include', //this is important
            body: body
        }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                const id = Date.now();
                localStorage.sid = id; //this is temporary
                return res.json()
            } else {
                return res.json()
            }
        })
         // you can ignore this part
        .then(async resp => {
            return resp
        })
}
```

Side-note: Your browser automatically handles the `httpOnly` cookies you send from your server however the `credentials: 'include'` **needs** to be included in your subsequent `fetch` requests.

In one of my main parent components, the `login` function is called:

```
login = async (user) => {
  this.setState({ error: null });
  await adapter.login(user).then(data => {
    if (!data.error) {
      this.setState({session: "active"})
    } else if (data.error && data.error.status === 401) {
        // this is so I can handle displaying invalid credentials errors and stuff
        this.setState({ error: data.error, loading: false });
    }
  });
}
```

I also have a `middleware` on the server-side that is run before any of the code in the routes to verify that the user making the request is actually authorized. This is also what handles `access token` expiration for me; if the `access token` has expired, I use the `refresh token` to generate a new `access token` and send it back in the `httpOnly` cookie, again with a status of 200 so the user experience isn't jarring. This does of course mean that your `refresh token` would have to live longer than your `access token` (I haven't decided how long in my case yet, but I'm thinking either 7 or 14 days) though as far as I'm aware that is okay to do.

One last thing, the parent component I referred to earlier calls a validate function which is a `fetch` request to the server within its `componentDidMount` so that the user is verified each time the component mounts, and then I've included some conditional rendering:

```
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
          {
            !localStorage.sid && <LoginForms {...yourPropsHere}/>
          }       
          {
            this.state.loading && <Loading />
          }
          {
            localStorage.sid && this.state.session === "active" && <Route path="/" render={(props) => <Root error={this.state.error} {...props}/>}/>
          }
          </div>
        );
    }
```

I've gone the conditional rendering route as I couldn't get `PrivateRoute` to work properly in the time that I had, but either should be fine.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your login API should return JWT token and how long it should be live.

Your login API response would be like :

```
{ 
  jwt: your jwt token, 
  duration: in seconds 
}
```

Use **universal-cookies** NPM to store this result into cookies.

For more details how to manipulate with cookies, visit

https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie

For setting cookies your code like:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set(name of cookies, jwt value from API call, {
    maxAge: duration,
});
```

Above code store the jwt cookies in browser and after maxAge automatically remove it from browser.

**So for identifying session is present or not, you should check after specific interval cookies has present in browser or not. If cookies has present in browser then session is on, otherwise session has expired.**