# How do I create a cookie after a response from the server? react

Tags: reactjs

I have a request for authorization to the server:

```
axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/sign-in",
      { ...values },
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const { token } = res.data;
     //there I need to save coookie with token that came from server
    })
```

after successful authorization, the server sends the token, how can I save this token in the cookie with the httpOnly flag?

Comment: You can use [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) package. It's very simple to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a cookie in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826992/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `universal-cookie` package to do this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
 
const cookies = new Cookies();

...

.then((res) => {
  const { token } = res.data;
 cookies.set('token', token , { httpOnly: true, path: "/" });
})
```

Comment: for some reason the cookie is not saved

Comment: How do you know it not saved?

Comment: when the cookie is saved I see that I am logged in and in the cookies tab it is not visible that the cookie is saved

Comment: do you know why cookie don't want to save?

Comment: You can add `path` to make sure all page in your app can use this cookie

Comment: i did like this: cookies.set("token", token, { path: "/", httpOnly: true }); But it doesn't save

Comment: but without httpOnly it saved, but i need to save it with httponly

Comment: only the server can access the cookie. The client is not