# How to Keep User Data Persistent in React with React-Router-Dom and Context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-context

I'm working on the login of a client-side application. I'm using **React** with **TypeScript**. I'm using **react-router-dom**. I'm using **Context** to store the logged-in user's data, but when I refresh the page, the data stored in the **context** is lost. I need this information to persist, and I'm not sure if a **React context** is the best option.

My main concern is that I need to protect the routes for logged-in and non-logged-in users. I have users with different roles, and I need them to be redirected to their respective dashboards when they try to access a route that doesn't belong to them. However, to determine the type of user that's logged in, I need to have their username and role stored somehow immediately after they log in.

Should I use **context** or is there a better option to do this?

I have the following code:

in **app.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not found page</h1>} />

        {/* Routes manage for user no logged */}
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route index path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

        {/* Routes manage for officer */}
        <Route path="/officer/*" element={<OfficerPage />}>
          <Route path="officerwelcome" element={<Welcome user="Encargado" />} />
        </Route>

        {/* Routes manage for manager */}
        <Route path="/manager/*" element={<ManagerPage />}>
          <Route
            path="managerwelcome"
            element={<Welcome user="Subgerente" />}
          />
        </Route>

        {/* Routes manage for assintant */}
        <Route path="/assistant/*" element={<AssistantPage />}>
          <Route
            path="assistantwelcome"
            element={<Welcome user="Asistente" />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

in Login page:

```
authService
      .login(data)
      .then((response) => {
        Cookies.set("token", response.token, { expires: 1 });
        const role = response.role
        navigate(`/${role}/${role}welcome`, { replace: true });
        login(response.username, response.role);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
```

Context:

```
type UserData = {
  username: string;
  role: string;
};

type AuthContextType = {
  user: UserData | null;
  login: (username: string, role: string) => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData | null>(null);

  const login = (username: string, role: string) => {
    setUser({ username, role });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I use cookies to store the token of the api that I also created

This code is fully functional but i have the problem described.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's this line:

```
Cookies.set("token", response.token, { expires: 1 });
```

I think the `expires` field wants a Date object.
See: [How can I set a cookie in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826992/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-in-react)

Comment: I have no problems with token storage. but with the context.

Comment: I have no problems with token storage. but with the context.